# How can we capture change events of LayersControl component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, leaflet, react-leaflet

For example, when changing the base layer (radio buttons) or toggling an overlay on/off (checkboxes), how can we capture the change events in order to update other aspects of state in an application. Thanks in advance, open to any type of solution. Pseudo-code:

```
<Map>
    <LayersControl position='topright' change={this.handleLayerControlsChange}>
        <BaseLayer checked name='Map 1'>
            <TileLayer url={map1} />
        </BaseLayer>
        <BaseLayer checked name='Map 2'>
            <TileLayer url={map2} />
        </BaseLayer>
        <Overlay name='Overlay 1'>
            <LayerGroup>
                <GeoJSON data={overlayData1} />
            </LayerGroup>
        </Overlay>
        <Overlay name='Overlay 2'>
            <LayerGroup>
                <GeoJSON data={overlayData2} />
            </LayerGroup>
        </Overlay>
    </LayersControl>
</Map>
```

Comment: It's right in the docs: https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/events and if you follow the link there you'll find https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-layer-events

Answer (score 2):

Of course... hours and hours and it's only after posting a question that the solution is found. The map has a `whenReady` event (which I was already using it just wasn't in the pseudo-code) which upon looking at the [Leaflet Docs on the Map Events](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-event) there's a `baselayerchange` that can be used. Pseudo-code, that maybe helps someone else at some point:

```
baseLayerChange = event => {
    console.log('baseLayerChange event', event);
}

whenReadyHandler = event => {
    const { target } = event;
    target.on('baselayerchange', this.baseLayerChange);
}

<Map whenReady={this.whenReadyHandler}>
    <LayersControl position='topright' change={this.handleLayerControlsChange}>
        <BaseLayer checked name='Map 1'>
            <TileLayer url={map1} />
        </BaseLayer>
        <BaseLayer checked name='Map 2'>
            <TileLayer url={map2} />
        </BaseLayer>
        <Overlay name='Overlay 1'>
            <LayerGroup>
                <GeoJSON data={overlayData1} />
            </LayerGroup>
        </Overlay>
        <Overlay name='Overlay 2'>
            <LayerGroup>
                <GeoJSON data={overlayData2} />
            </LayerGroup>
        </Overlay>
    </LayersControl>
</Map>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Only change is, and I'm not sure if it's because react-leaflet updated since your answer, but <Map> is now <MapComponent>.